# Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.3 modal can't visible when using with fade in React JS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

**Demo:**

```js
closeConfirrmDialog() {
  var modal = document.getElementById('profileConfirm');
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div className="modal fade" id="profileConfirm" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div className="modal-dialog" role="document" style={{width:"500px"}}>
    <div className="modal-content">
   <div className="modal-header">
     <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Updation success</h4>
   </div>
 <div className="modal-body"> Profile has been updated successfully.. </div>
 <div className="modal-footer">
   <div className="pull-right">
  <button className="twk-uix-button twk-uix-button-size-default twk-uix-button-primary twk-uix-button-empty comment-simplebox-submit twk-uix-sessionlink" type="button" style={{background:"#5cb85c", color:"#fff"}} onClick={this.closeConfirrmDialog.bind(this)} >OK</button>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Modal is hiding backside

> I need modal fade but it is hiding as given image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, fade has opactiy 0 by default in bootstrap.css

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
    transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
```

over write if you need or use modal **fade in**. Hope it helps !!!